# Create new array based on array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array as follows

```
[ 'test123', '', 'testabc' ]
```

How can i make an array based on the array index of this array.My desired output is `[ '1', '0','1']`. If any element is there in the index it should give 1 otherwise 0. What is best way to generate an array like this in nodejs.

Comment: `const newArray = arr.map(item => item? '1' : '0');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map`

```js
var data = [ 'test123', '', 'testabc' ],
    result = data.map(v => v? '1' :'0');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and simple way:

```
var myarray = [ 'test123', '', 'testabc' ];
var newarray = []; 

for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; ++i){
  if(myarray[i].length > 0){
     newarray.push('1');
   }
   else newarray.push('0');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [ 'test123', '', 'testabc' ];
var newarray = []; 

array.forEach(function(item){
   if(item.length > 0) {
     newarray.push('1');
   } else {
       newarray.push('0');
    }
});

console.log(newarray);
```

You can loop through your array using for or forEach,

if the length is greather than 0 , we pushing the value '1' into empty array 
called **newarray** else we pushing '0'.

Comment: Note, literals do not have length property. So if the value is number or null or object, this logic will push `0`. Though based on the input provided by OP, this should work just fine

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Loop over array and convert value into boolean. You can do that using `!!`
- Then convert this boolean value to numeric. True is converted to `1` and false is converted to `0`.

```js
var arr = [ 'test123', '', 'testabc' ];
var result = arr.map((x) => +!!x);
console.log(result)
```